# Cannot find reference 'Session' in 'imported module src.flask_session'

Tags: python, flask

Im trying to import Session from Flask-Session but I get the following error

> Cannot find reference 'Session' in 'imported module src.flask_session'

so I believe that the Server-side Session is not working on my app.

I have installed the Flask-Session package (using `pip install Flask-Session`) and I see it in the site-packages folder of my project's venv.

When I start importing the module the autocomplete that appears is the following:[import module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb5zq.png)

Environment: PyCharm 2022.2.3 (community edition), Python 3.11

Did I do something wrong when installing or importing the module? How do I fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.